# Trying to call a class method in Google Maps Marker click event callback, in jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I have a class in jQuery that handles a google map and its markers.
After each marker creation, i add a click listener for each marker :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
    //Do something with event
});
```

However, i would like to use a function from the class instead :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", this.onVehiculeClick.bind(this));
onVehiculeClick: function(event) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(event);
    //Do something with event
}
```

It is working well on firefox and chrome : it's logging **this** (my object) and the google map event. But not in Safari or IE (and also on some other versions of Firefox) : it is not calling the onVehiculeClick method and if i add a console.log right after the google.maps.event.addListener, nothing is output.

If i remove the *.bind(this)* part, the method is called but i lose the **this** context and **this** will stand for the google map object. I also tried to add a *var that = this* in the constructor but it is undefined in the method context.

I found something that i think might help me here : [Google Maps JS API v3: Need to access Marker Object from inside the Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513518/google-maps-js-api-v3-need-to-access-marker-object-from-inside-the-event-handle) but it's using prototype and i can't find any equivalent of the curry method in jQuery.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you using a library? .bind is not supported natively in IE<9, Safari, or Firefox<4. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind for a shim. If you provide more code and/or a link I'm sure there is an easy solution.

Comment: I'm using only jQuery and jQuery Inherit, full code after. Do you know any workaround for *.bind*, or maybe if i can get each marker's id so that i can use jQuery binding instead of Google's ?

Comment: I cannot answer myself before 2 hours ..I will post the script later. You can find it here meanwhile : http://www.2shared.com/document/gGg35IeU/gmap.html or http://uploading.com/files/c527addc/gmap.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your addVehicule method to this:

```
    addVehicule: function(vehicule) {
    try {
        var marker = this.addMarker(vehicule.latitude, vehicule.longitude);
        var that = this;
        //Observe clicks on vehicule
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event){
            that.onVehiculeClick(event)
        });

        this.vehicules.push(vehicule);
    } catch (error) {}
}
```

Comment: That's working ! Thanks a lot :) I tried to set *var that = this* in the constructor method and then use it the same way that you did, but it was not working. How come do we have to declare it in the method context ?

Comment: If you declare it in the constructor then 'that' is only available in the constructor. By declaring it in the method it is available in the click event too.